# Make less use alternate screen, but only if entire file won't fit on one screen

Tags: linux, tmux, gnu-screen, less

I'd like `less` to quit immediately if the entire file can be displayed within one screen. For this, I'd use the `-F` option:

```
-F or --quit-if-one-screen

    Causes less to automatically exit if the entire file can be
    displayed on the first screen.
```

The gotcha: when the file is longer than one screen long, I'd like to be able to use the alternate screen. As such, I don't want to pass `-X`:

```
-X or --no-init

    Disables sending the termcap initialization and deinitialization
    strings to the terminal. This is sometimes desirable if the
    deinitialization string does something unnecessary, like
    clearing the screen.
```

Note that if you set `-F` without `-X`, doing `less some-short-file` produces no visible output, because it appears only in the alternate screen, which goes away as soon as `less` exits, which is immediately.

Why I want this: I have tmux bindings set up such that I can scroll with the mousewheel when in alternate screen mode (ie. in `less` and in things which use it as a pager: `git`, `ack`, `ag`, `man` etc).

Wondering if I have to replace `less` with some wrapper script or function which checks the screen height and conditionally decides whether to invoke `less -FX` or `less`, or whether such a thing would be too tricky to implement when reading from a pipe (in which case it might have to do something simpler, like default to `less`).

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/a/106644/322531

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question appears to contain all of the relevant information.  A simple wrapper script would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -t 0 && $# = 1 ]
then
    want=$(wc -l "$1" |sed -e 's/[[:space:]].*//')
    have=$(stty -a |grep -E " rows [[:digit:]]" | sed -e 's/^.* rows //' -e 's/;.*//')
    if [ $want -le $have ]
    then
        less -FX "$1"
    else
        less "$1"
    fi
else
    less "$1"
fi
```

which checks if the standard input is a terminal, and if so, counts the number of lines in the file, comparing it to the number on the screen.  Handling options would complicate things of course.

Someone might post a more concise script; this works in a quick test here.

Comment: After posting, found [this similar question with some alternative answers here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107315/less-quit-if-one-screen-without-no-init/).

Comment: yes... but bash's `$LINES` and `$COLUMNS` are unreliable.  I would never use those in a script (ymmv).