# screen always clear screen upon exit - how to disable it

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tmux, gnu-screen

Seems that unlike `less` that can switch off clearing screen -- 
['less' command clearing screen upon exit - how to switch it off?](https://superuser.com/questions/106637/less-command-clearing-screen-upon-exit-how-to-switch-it-off)

the `screen` [always clear screen upon exit](https://serverfault.com/questions/253148/disable-clear-at-start-of-screen-via-screenrc). That's very inconvenient.

How do you workaround it?
Would `tmux` able to?

Thanks

Comment: I found a work-round which makes `less` open in the same screen as the terminal, but there were too many side-effects for it to be usable. When I want to retain the screen afterwards, I use `more`.

Comment: @AFH, good to know. This is more on `screen` rather than `less` though, but thx all the same.

Comment: If I really want to see the last page displayed on exit from `less` (eg while showing part of a manual page), I select all and copy, then `xclip -o` after exit.